# How do I turn a polling system into an Rx.Net IObservable?

Tags: c#, xna, system.reactive, monogame, rx.net

I have a game (based on MonoGame / XNA) with an update method like so:

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    component.Update(gameTime);
}
```

I would like to convert this to the Reactive pattern. My current solution is:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    updateSubject = new Subject<GameTime>();

    component = new Component();

    updateSubject.Subscribe((gameTime) => component.Update(gameTime));
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    updateSubject.OnNext(gameTime);
}
```

I am new to Rx so I am still learning the best way of doing things. I read that `Subject` should be avoided and `Observable.Create` should be used instead.

Is `Subject` appropriate here?

How could I use `Observable.Create` in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key issue you're facing here is that you need a source for your observable. In general you can create observables from a variety of sources from events, delegates, tasks, many of the observable extensions (like `.Interval` or `.Generate`), and subjects.

In your case you must have a source that you can have code, external to your observable, push values to. In this case a subject is perfectly fine, but you could just use a delegate also.

If you use a subject then your code is fine. The only downside is that you could call `updateSubject.OnCompleted` and finish the observable.

If you want to use a delegate then your code could look like this:

```
private Action<GameTime> updateGameTime = null;

public void Initialize()
{
    component = new Component();

    Observable
        .FromEvent<GameTime>(a => updateGameTime += a, a => updateGameTime -= a)
        .Subscribe((gameTime) => component.Update(gameTime));
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    updateGameTime(gameTime);
}
```

In this way the only thing you can do with `updateGameTime` is pass in a new `GameTime` - you can't "accidentally" end the sequence.

Now the whole issue with using subjects versus `Observable.Create` is one of state. In your code you need state, so a subject is OK. In general though, and whenever possible, it is advisable to encapsulate state - and that's what `Observable.Create` does for you.

Take this example:

```
var i = -1;
var query =
    Observable
        .Range(0, 10).Select(x =>
        {
            i = -i * 2;
            return x * i;
        });
```

If I subscribe to this observable twice I get these two sequences:

(1)

```
0 
-4 
16 
-48 
128 
-320 
768 
-1792 
4096 
-9216
```

(2)

```
0 
-4096 
16384 
-49152 
131072 
-327680 
786432 
-1835008 
4194304 
-9437184
```

The sequence changes because I used state (i.e. `var i = -1;`).

Had I written the code with `Observable.Create` I could avoid this state:

```
var query =
    Observable
        .Create<int>(o =>
        {
            var i = -1;
            return
                Observable
                .Range(0, 10).Select(x =>
                {
                    i = -i * 2;
                    return x * i;
                })
                .Subscribe(o);
        });
```

It is still the same query, but the state is encapsulated, so if I subscribe twice now I get:

(1)

```
0 
-4 
16 
-48 
128 
-320 
768 
-1792 
4096 
-9216
```

(2)

```
0 
-4 
16 
-48 
128 
-320 
768 
-1792 
4096 
-9216
```

There are times when writing complex queries that you might think that using a subject would make it much easier, and in general, that's where mistakes occur. You should always try to find a pure operator approach before using subjects in this case. If you can't then encapsulate the use of a subject in `Observable.Create`.

It's times like yours that using a subject is fine because you need that external state.

Answer (score 1):

Just pointing out that you code unnessecarily uses Rx.

```
public void Initialize()
{
    //updateSubject = new Subject<GameTime>();

    component = new Component();

    //updateSubject.Subscribe((gameTime) => component.Update(gameTime));
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    //updateSubject.OnNext(gameTime);
    component.Update(gameTime)
}
```

Here I have removed the `Subject` and just call directly through to the `component`s `Update` method, to illustrate the point.

Perhaps you are looking for a private method of polling? In which case `Observable.Interval` could be a good place to start.

Comment: I gave a minimal example for SO. The real code is more complex than this.

Comment: That is good to hear. But if this is a complete minimal verifiable example, then the Subject (and thus Rx) is redundant. I don't believe you provide enough information to provide a sensible answer.

Comment: An example of where my `IObservable<GameTime>` is useful is processing input. If I also have an `IObservable<KeyboardState>` then I can window it using my `GameTime` stream.